# Share multiple images from app internal memory

Tags: android, image, share

I have healthy working code to share single image from my app's internal memory using `FileProvider` facility given in `android-support-v4.jar` library.

Here is the code snippet

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MSafeGalleryActivity.this, "com.packagename.fileprovider", file);
final Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(SafeGalleryActivity.this)
        .setType("image/jpeg")
        .setStream(uri)
        .setChooserTitle("Share with")
        .createChooserIntent()
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

startActivity(intent);
```

If you see the code it accept only one URI in `setStream()` method.
So Please can you help me out here to share multiple images from my app's internal memory.

Answer (score 0):

To share multiple images, I use the following code:

```
ArrayList<Uri> imageUris = new ArrayList<>();
// Put your file uri in imageUris
// ...
// Create intent
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUris);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
// Grant permission to read files
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
// Start chooser activity
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_send)))
```